# Find three subspaces $V_1, V_2, V_3$ of $V=F[X]$ such that $V=V_1\oplus V_2\oplus V_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, direct-sum

What are all subspaces of $F[X]$? One could say that the even degree polynomials  and the odd degree are subspaces and so put that $F[X]=(X^{2i+1})\oplus (X^{2j})\oplus (0)$ or $F[X]=F[X]\oplus(0)\oplus (0)$ ?

Comment: Do you imply that the space of even degree polynomials is a subspace? It's not, for example $X^2$  and $X^2-X$ are even polynomials, but $X^2-(X^2-X)=X$ is not even.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Why $X^2-X$ is a polynomial pair, is not $X$ raised to 1? Should not all appear with even powers?

Comment: The degree of a polynomial $P(X)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iX^i$ is  $n$ when $a_n\neq 0$. Thus clearly $\deg(X^2-X)=2$. You are thinking about the subspace generated by $1,X^2,X^4,X^6,\dots$ This is not the subspace of even degree polynomials.

Comment: Also, there are infinitely many subspace of $F[X]$, for example $F_{< n}[X]=\left\{P(X)\in F[X]\mid \deg(P(X))<n\right\}$ are all non-isomorphic subspaces for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: Also, writing $\oplus (0)$ is very useless.

Comment: @Mathematician42 
Okay, so what subspaces would serve me to form direct sum?

Comment: Take any basis $\beta$ of $F[X]$ and write $\beta=\beta_1\cup\beta_2\cup \beta_3$ with $\beta_i\cap\beta_j\neq \emptyset \Leftrightarrow i=j$. Then define $V_i$ as the subspace with basis $\beta_i$. Then $F[X]=V_1\oplus V_2\oplus V_3$ where each space is non-zero. These are all non-trivial decompositions into the direct sum of three subspaces.